mutual information between two discrete and a continuous variables
I am wondering what is the best way to compute the mutual information between discrete ($a_i$ or $a_j$) and continuous $h_{ik}$ values such as this $I(a_i;a_j|h_{ik})$ where $k\in \{1,2,...,K\}$ and $i,j\in\{1,2,...,N\}$. Here is my code for computing it in python:
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la
from numpy import log
from scipy.special import digamma
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree, KDTree
def build_tree(points):
   if points.shape[1] >= 20:
       return BallTree(points, metric="chebyshev")
   return KDTree(points, metric="chebyshev")


def add_noise(x, intens=1e-10):
    # small noise to break degeneracy, see doc.
    return x + intens * np.random.random_sample(x.shape)


def query_neighbors(tree, x, k):
    return tree.query(x, k=k + 1)[0][:, k]

# CONTINUOUS ESTIMATORS


def entropy(x, k=3, base=2):
    """The classic K-L k-nearest neighbor continuous entropy estimator
    x should be a list of vectors, e.g. x = [[1.3], [3.7], [5.1], [2.4]]
    if x is a one-dimensional scalar and we have four samples
    """
    assert k <= len(x) - 1, "Set k smaller than num. samples - 1"
    x = np.asarray(x)
    n_elements, n_features = x.shape
    x = add_noise(x)
    tree = build_tree(x)
    nn = query_neighbors(tree, x, k)
    const = digamma(n_elements) - digamma(k) + n_features * log(2)
    return (const + n_features * np.log(nn).mean()) / log(base)


# DISCRETE ESTIMATORS
def entropyd(sx, base=2):
    """Discrete entropy estimator
    sx is a list of samples
    """
    unique, count = np.unique(sx, return_counts=True, axis=0)
    # Convert to float as otherwise integer division results in all 0 for proba.
    proba = count.astype(float) / len(sx)
    # Avoid 0 division; remove probabilities == 0.0 (removing them does not change the entropy estimate as 0 * log(1/0) = 0.
    proba = proba[proba > 0.0]
    return np.sum(proba * np.log(1.0 / proba)) / log(base)

def mix_entropy(discrete_data, continuous_data, k=3):
    """
    Computes the entropy of a mixture of discrete and continuous variables.

    :param discrete_data: numpy array of shape (n_samples,) representing discrete data
    :param continuous_data: numpy array of shape (n_samples, n_features) representing continuous data
    :param k: number of nearest neighbors to use for continuous entropy estimation
    :return: combined entropy estimate
    """
    discrete_data = discrete_data.flatten()
    # Compute entropy of the discrete part
    H_discrete = entropyd(discrete_data)

    # For each discrete value, compute the entropy of the corresponding continuous subset
    unique_values = np.unique(discrete_data)
    H_conditional_continuous = 0.0

    # Ensure discrete_data and continuous_data have compatible dimensions
    if discrete_data.shape[0] != continuous_data.shape[0]:
        raise ValueError(f"Mismatch in dimensions: discrete_data has shape {discrete_data.shape}, but continuous_data has shape {continuous_data.shape}")

    for value in unique_values:
        subset_continuous_data = continuous_data[discrete_data == value]
        if len(subset_continuous_data) > k:
            H_conditional_continuous += (len(subset_continuous_data) / len(continuous_data)) * entropy(subset_continuous_data, k)
        else:
            # Handle cases with insufficient data
            H_conditional_continuous += 0  # Or add some default behavior here

    # Combined entropy
    return H_discrete + H_conditional_continuous




def joint_conditional_entropy(a_i, a_j, h_ik, k=3, base=2):
    """
    Computes the joint conditional entropy H(a_i, a_j | h_{ik}),
    where a_i and a_j are discrete and h_{ik} is continuous.

    :param a_i: Discrete actions of agent i (numpy array of shape (n_samples,))
    :param a_j: Discrete actions of agent j (numpy array of shape (n_samples,))
    :param h_ik: Continuous hidden state of agent i (numpy array of shape (n_samples, hidden_dim))
    :param k: Number of nearest neighbors to use for continuous entropy estimation
    :param base: Logarithm base for entropy calculation
    :return: Joint conditional entropy H(a_i, a_j | h_{ik})
    """
    # Discretize hidden states if needed (e.g., bin them)
    # You could also use a k-NN based estimation for the continuous variable

    # Combine a_i and a_j into a joint variable (assuming discrete values)
    joint_discrete = np.stack([a_i, a_j], axis=1)
    n_samples = h_ik.shape[0]
    # Number of unique joint action pairs
    unique_pairs, counts = np.unique(joint_discrete, axis=0, return_counts=True)
    conditional_entropy = 0.0

    for pair, count in zip(unique_pairs, counts):
        # Subset h_ik for the current pair of (a_i, a_j)
        mask = np.all(joint_discrete == pair, axis=1)
        h_ik_given_pair = h_ik[mask]

        # Compute the entropy of h_ik given the pair (a_i, a_j)
        if len(h_ik_given_pair) > k:
            H_hik_given_pair = entropy(h_ik_given_pair, k=k)  # Use k-NN for continuous entropy
            conditional_entropy += (count / n_samples) * H_hik_given_pair

    return conditional_entropy


def conditional_mutual_information(a_i, a_j, h_ik, k=3, base=2):
    """Compute I(a_i; a_j | h_ik) where a_i and a_j are discrete and h_ik is continuous"""
    #I(a_i; a_j | h_ik) = H(a_i | h_ik) + H(a_j | h_ik) - H(a_i, a_j | h_ik)
    #= [H(a_i, h_ik) - H(h_ik)] + [H(a_j, h_ik) - H(h_ik)] - H(a_i, a_j | h_ik)
    #= H(a_i, h_ik) + H(a_j, h_ik) - H(a_i, a_j | h_ik) - 2*H(h_ik)
    # Ensure a_i and a_j are 1D arrays
    # Combine a_i and a_j into a single 2D array


    # Compute joint entropy H(a_i, a_j, h_ik)
    joint_entropy = joint_conditional_entropy(a_i.flatten(), a_j.flatten(), h_ik, k)
    print("compute H(a_i, h_ik)")
    # Compute H(a_i, h_ik)
    h_a_i = mix_entropy(a_i, h_ik, k)
    print("compute H(a_j, h_ik)")
    # Compute H(a_j, h_ik)
    h_a_j = mix_entropy(a_j, h_ik, k)

    # Compute H(h_ik)
    h_h = entropy(h_ik, k, base)

    # Compute conditional mutual information
    cmi = h_a_i + h_a_j - joint_entropy - 2*h_h

    return max(cmi, 0)  # Ensure non-negativity due to estimation errors

Is this method correct?
